# Is there a way to have callable objects in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, object, language-features, callable

If for example I have a class named A. Can I make an object be callable, just like Python does? For example :

```
def myObject = new A()
myObject()
```

and that would call some object method. Can it be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Groovy only closures are callable by default. E.g. Classes are not callable out of the box. If necessary you can dynamically add a call method to a type's [ExpandoMetaClass](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/ExpandoMetaClass.html) to make all instances of that type *callable*.

Hint: you can try out all code sample using the [GroovyConsole](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/)

Closures are *callable* by default in Groovy:

```
// A closure
def doSomething = { println 'do something'}
doSomething()
    
// A closure with arguments
def sum = {x, y -> x + y}
sum(5,3)
sum.call(5,3)
    
// Currying
def sum5 = sum.curry(5)
sum5(3)
```

To make all instances of a specific type *callable* you can dynamically add a call method to its meta class:

```
MyObject.metaClass.call = { println 'I was called' }
def myObject = new MyObject()
myObject()
```

If you rather only make a specific instance *callable* you can dynamically add a call method to its meta class:

```
def myObject = new MyObject()
myObject.metaClass.call = { println 'Called up on' }
myObject()
```

Comment: I noticed it works even without altering the metaclass. If I add a method named `call`, it will get called.

Comment: Great answer! The ExapandoMetaClass link is broken though.